# Calculate probability of being in the top-N based on pairwise probabilities

Tags: probability

I have a set of, say, 20 documents and I have calculated all the pairwise probabilities that `doc_x` is more important than `doc_y` (e.g. `P(doc_1 > doc_2) = 0.7`). However, the probabilities may be inconsistent i.e. there may exist three documents where `P(doc_1 > doc_2) > P(doc_2 > doc_3) > P(doc_3 > doc_1)`.

Is there a way to estimate the probability of each document belonging in the top-N most important documents? In other words, how can I say that `P(doc_1 belongs in the top-5 documents) = ...%`?

**EDIT:**
The probabilities mentioned above are the output of a machine learning model that is trained to return the 'probability' of doc_1 > doc_2. So, they are the output of a binary classification model. Therefore, they are estimates of a probability but not a 'real' probability of some underlying distribution.

Let's suppose we always have 20 documents (no more, no less) and all their pairwise probability estimates. Is there a way to estimate the probability of `doc_x` being in the top-N (N = [1, 2, ... 20]) most important ones? For the sake of simplicity, we can ignore that they may be inconsistent.

It's obvious that `P(doc_x belongs in the top-20 docs) = 1`.

Comment: I think you have to Go back a step and explain how you are getting inconsistent probabilities...maybe you need to fix that first. In what sense are they estimates..

Comment: These probabilities are the output of a machine learning model. So, I cannot fix that. Even if I could do that, how would I get the top-N probability I'm looking for?

Comment: This question remains unclear when you do not specify the probabilities. I imagine that they are some 'observed' quantities and not true underlying probabilities (because in that latter case I do not see how the algebra of being more important works).

Comment: is it possible to have documents of equal importance? Such that $P (doc_i < doc_j) + P ( doc_j < doc_i) $ is not necessarily equal to one.

Comment: @MartijnWeterings In all cases `P(doc_1<doc_2)+P(doc_2<doc_1) = 1`.

I'm looking for either some statistical proof that can lead to what I'm looking for, or for any heuristic than can do the job.

Comment: Stergios could you explain more about your problem and what you mean by your probabilities? Are they estimates? How did you obtain them, what kind of sampling? And why/ how do you get the inconsistent values. Currently your question is too vague.

Comment: @MartijnWeterings I've added some more details in the post above. Thank you!

Comment: What is the situation that you are needing the top list for?

Comment: @MartijnWeterings I do not need the top list. I need the probability of being in the top-k list for each item. I'm thinking whether I can use the pairwise probabilities to do that or whether I need to build ML classifiers for each case (e.g. one classifier would predict if an item is in the top-k or not [build a model for various values of k]).

Comment: @Stergios, I meant to ask about the context of your problem. Currently I do not get what you mean by top-k list. How do you rank the books for such list? That's why I asked for the goal of such list, or probability (whatever the number is that you are looking for, what does it mean?).

Comment: What does the event $doc_i > doc_j$ mean?

Comment: @MartijnWeterings: OK, got it. The 'documents' mentioned above were just illustrative; I thought they would be an easy example. My actual data refer to Formula 1 data. So, for each race there are 20 drivers and my ML model predicts all pairwise probabilities of `driver_x finishing ahead of driver_y`. 

I want to calculate the chance of `driver_x` finishing in the top-k positions.

Comment: In that case the answer by @Jay is correct.  You have the paradox and need to deal with dependency of the different P (doc_i  < doc_ j). The situations when doc_i < doc_j occurs are likely related (e.g. when a car crashes or when a certain track favours some drivers more than others). You could have all pairwise couples larger for some driver but still have another be more likely to reach a certain top position because, say, they are slower but more reliable (e.g. they may perform terrible almost everywhere except in monaco)

Comment: OK. But @Jay's answer ignores the pairwise probabilities entirely. I want my probabilities to show that, say, Hamilton is more likely to finish in the top-5 compared to Leclerc.

Comment: Otherwise, in case of independence, you could use for each driver j a https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_binomial_distribution with p_i the probability for a driver j to beat driver i and the outcome is the probability to reach position k (and the cdf will be the probability for the top-k).

Comment: Jay's answer is correct in the fact that you have this paradox situation. You will not be able to calculate the probabilities for top k based on pairwise probabilities. E.g. consider the following race results: $\begin {array} \\ 1-2-3-4-5 \\ 2-1-3-4-5 \\ 3-1-2-4-5 \\ 5-1-2-3-4 \\ 5-1-2-3-4\end{array} $ Driver 5 has the lowest pairwise probabilities but the highest probability to be top 1. (this is an exaggerated example for clarity but the principle is realistic, imagine the fastest car being very unreliable)

Comment: OK, but in your example, `driver_1` has a higher probability of being in the top-3 compared to `driver_5`. How can I capture that with @Jay's answer?

Comment: @Stergios, the top-3 doesn't matter here. It is an *example* using the top-1, just to show that the pairwise probabilities do not translate well to overall top-k. The pairwise probabilities are not independent; it is not like 19 coin-tosses to decide where a driver will likely end up; when a driver does better on a particular circuit he will beat many coin tosses, more than expected based on an independent model. If you wish then you could use the poisson binomial model that I mentioned but expect a larger dispersion due to the correlation/dependency (which you can not correct because unknown

Comment: OK, I understand that the pairwise comparisons are not independent. I just wanted to find out if there's any 'heuristic' or some concrete statistical methodology to estimate that probability. Thanks a lot for your time. If you want to post an answer that what I'm asking is not possible, I'll accept it!

Comment: @Stergios It can be enticing to look for complex methods to hone our predictions, but a first principle in statistical models in parsimony. In this case, the most simple solution is to find the probability of a combination, which is both a heuristic and statistically informed solution. Ideally, you could use this probability as a prior and then calculate a posterior distribution of probabilities using empirical evidence.

Comment: so as @MartijnWeterings has also asked, why are you doing this? Alternative approaches would be eg to just predict the time of each driver (given that you now mention its formula 1 driving)

Comment: @seanv507 I need the probability of being in the top-k since this is what I need. Probably, I'll build ML classifiers to predict this probability. Anyway, thank you for your time!

Comment: @JaySchylerRaadt: Do you know how I could do what you're proposing?

Comment: @Stergios I have edited my answer. Take it with a grain of salt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This situation is called the Condorcet Paradox, which is a violation of the assumption of transitivity in social science research. An often-used solution is to either treat the majority decision of a group as a single decision or to dichotomize choices. Treating the majority as the final decision is common in democracies and dichotomous choices is the de facto rule in voting in some democracies. There is a great [walk-through on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condorcet_paradox). In general, it is a function of the number of choices.

EDIT:

I'm going to change around your symbols a bit, because $N$ usually means the size of a population (in my world). I'm also introducing your "top" number as the variable $k$. In your post you want to consider the case $N=20$ and $1\leq k\leq20$.

As you said, the probability of a document being in the top for $N=20$ is 1.0. In other words, there are 20 ways of being in the top 20. Flipping this around, how many ways can a document be in the top 1? There are 20 ways that a document can be the top document. Now we have some bounds.

Stretching further, how many ways are there to be in the top-2? Let $d$ be a matrix with $k$ columns and $x$ rows, where x is the number of ways a document can appear in the top $k$.

For $k=2$, $d=[(doc1,doc2),(doc1,doc3),...,(doc1,doc20),(doc2,doc1),(doc3,doc1),(doc20,doc1)]$

This matrix has 190 rows, or $x=190$, which means there are 190 unique *combinations*. I believe your problem really is based on combinations, where the number of ways to be in the top $k$ is given by $$\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$$

Working off our "bounds" before, we have a distribution of outcomes[image: Distribution of Combinations]

The skew and kurtosis of this distribution are within reasonable limits for a normal distribution, so I say you can treat this distribution of combinations as a normal distribution.

Thus, using a z-table or using a function like `pnorm(qnorm(1/n-k+1))` in `R`, you get the probability of such combinations.

[image: Probabilities of being in the top k]

Here is the code I used:

```
require(psych)
outcomes=c(NULL)
for(i in 1:20){outcomes=c(outcomes,choose(20,i))}
barplot(outcomes,main="C(20,k)",ylab="Combinations",xlab="k")
axis(1,at=c(1:20),tick=F)
describe(outcomes)
my=function(k){return(pnorm(qnorm(1/(20-k+1))))}
pr=c(NULL)
for(i in 1:20){pr=c(pr,my(i))}
barplot(pr)
```

EDIT: I'm not sure if this will serve your purposes, but this is a simulated Bayesian analysis. I'm still very much a learner of Bayesian analysis, so take it with a grain of salt.

Pretend you have 10 observations of a good driver and 10 observations over bad driver and you want to know the posterior probability that they will finish in the top k, $k=10$.

```
obs.good=c(rep(1,9),2)
obs.bad=c(rep(20,9),19)
topk=10
```

You need to find the observed effects.

```
#calcualte effects
sum.good=summary(lm(obs.good~c(1:length(obs.good))))
sum.bad=summary(lm(obs.bad~c(1:length(obs.bad))))
#save effects
b.good=sum.good$coefficients[2,1]
b.bad=sum.bad$coefficients[2,1]
se.good=sum.good$coefficients[2,2]
se.bad=sum.bad$coefficients[2,2]
```

Then, calcualte the posterior probability, where the priors are determined by the distribution of combinations.

```
#calcualte posterior probability
require(BayesCombo)
mypph.good=pph(beta=b.good,se.beta=se.good,H.priors=c(pr[topk-1],pr[topk],1-pr[topk-1]))
mypph.bad=pph(beta=b.bad,se.beta=se.bad,H.priors=c(pr[topk-1],pr[topk],1-pr[topk-1]))
mypph.good$pphs
mypph.bad$pphs
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(mypph.good)
plot(mypph.bad)
```

See that the probability that the good driver will finish below 10th place is 96.1%, that they will finish in exactly 10th place is 3.3%, and that they will finish above 10th place is 0.6%. For the bad driver, the probability they will finish below 10th place is 37%, exactly 10th place 17.3%, and 45.7% above 10th place.

```
> mypph.good$pphs
         H<          H0          H> 
0.006427993 0.033005494 0.960566514 
> mypph.bad$pphs
       H<        H0        H> 
0.4571048 0.1727696 0.3701256
```

You can copy the code above and change your `topk` and `obs` variables. Like I said though, I am still learning Bayesian analysis, so maybe another user can add to what I've done here.

Comment: Thanks Jay! If we ignore the cyclic nature of my estimates, is there a way to get what I'm looking for?

Comment: @Stergios I have edited my answer

Comment: Thanks for putting this together! I see your point. I think what you're proposing gives the probability of any item in N being in the top-k. How can I use this to find the probability of a specific item being in the top-K taking into consideration their pairwise probabilities?

Comment: I guess that you might remove the first edit which makes little sense (or at least is unclear how it makes sense). Why use the combinations? At least in the case of a random shuffle this makes no sense $P(\text {top-fraction-x}) = x $ your formula does something very different.

Comment: @MartijnWeterings The distribution of combinations is used as a prior